# Flex 4.6 - XML appendChild unexpected behaviour

Tags: xml, apache-flex, mobile, flex4, appendchild

i want to use XML to save some configuration for elements in my app.
in my example i want to add 6 additional configuration sets to one "main" XML. each set can be config1 or config2.
In this case i added 3x config1 and 3x config2. if i trace my results i do not only get the wrong order of elements but also some "strange" binding behavior.
Of course this is a simplified example. my configuration sets are more complex (this is why i use seperate xml-objects for each config).

Can someone tell me how this is supposed to work ?

thanks,
quadword

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="160" creationComplete="init();">

<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XML id="mainConfig" format="e4x">
        <allConfigSets>
            <viewconfig>Baseconfig</viewconfig>
        </allConfigSets>
    </fx:XML>

    <fx:XML id="configSet1" format="e4x">
        <configSet><viewconfig>Set1</viewconfig></configSet>
    </fx:XML>

    <fx:XML id="configSet2" format="e4x">
        <configSet><viewconfig>Set2</viewconfig></configSet>
    </fx:XML>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init(): void {     

            mainConfig.appendChild(configSet1.viewconfig);
            mainConfig.appendChild(configSet1.viewconfig);
            mainConfig.appendChild(configSet1.viewconfig);
            mainConfig.appendChild(configSet2.viewconfig);
            mainConfig.appendChild(configSet2.viewconfig);
            mainConfig.appendChild(configSet2.viewconfig);

            // trace1 (see below): trace shows wrong order of elements
            trace (mainConfig);

            // trace2:(see below): changing data on original configSet seems to bind into mainConfig
            configSet1.viewconfig = "-";
            trace (mainConfig);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:Application>

Trace1:
<allConfigSets>
  <viewconfig>Baseconfig</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>Set1</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>Set2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>Set2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>Set2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>Set1</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>Set1</viewconfig>
</allConfigSets>

Trace2:
<allConfigSets>
  <viewconfig>Baseconfig</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>-</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>Set2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>Set2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>Set2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>-</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>-</viewconfig>
</allConfigSets>
```

Using AS3 XML Objects does not solve this issue:

```
private function init(): void {     
    var mainConfig:XML = <allConfigSets><viewconfig>0</viewconfig></allConfigSets>
    var configSet1:XML = <configSet><viewconfig>1</viewconfig></configSet>
    var configSet2:XML = <configSet><viewconfig>2</viewconfig></configSet>

    mainConfig.appendChild(configSet1.viewconfig);
    mainConfig.appendChild(configSet1.viewconfig);
    mainConfig.appendChild(configSet1.viewconfig);

    mainConfig.appendChild(configSet2.viewconfig);
    mainConfig.appendChild(configSet2.viewconfig);
    mainConfig.appendChild(configSet2.viewconfig);

    // trace1 (see below): trace shows wrong order of elements
    trace (mainConfig);

    // trace2:(see below): changing data on original configSet seems to bind into mainConfig
    configSet1.viewconfig = "-";
    trace (mainConfig);
}

Trace1:
<allConfigSets>
  <viewconfig>0</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>1</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>1</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>1</viewconfig>
</allConfigSets>

Trace2:
<allConfigSets>
  <viewconfig>0</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>-</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>2</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>-</viewconfig>
  <viewconfig>-</viewconfig>
</allConfigSets>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simultaneous change happens, because you keep appending multiple references to the exact same node (instead of new nodes).

Think of it this way (pseudo code!):

```
<node1>value</node1>

<node2>
    <reference>Go, look at node1!</reference>
    <reference>Go, look at node1!</reference>
    <reference>Go, look at node1!</reference>
</node2>
```

Whenever a reference is encountered, the value stored in node1 is returned. When you change that original value, since all the references point to the same node, they will also return the same new value.

To append new copies of your nodes instead of the original, use

```
mainConfig.appendChild(configSet1.viewconfig.copy());
```

but keep in mind that copy() returns a copy of the entire subtree of the node, not just the node itself.

As to why the order of elements is wrong, I am really at a loss - [XML#appendChild()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#appendChild%28%29) should add the elements to the end of the list of child nodes.  Does trace `(mainConfig.toXMLString());` return the same result?

Comment: of course i can see what is happening here but the question for me is:
is it really supposed to work this way ? 

in my opinion it makes no sense to reference the original object once it is append to the new object (in case of XML). looking at the resulting order "bug" it is questionable if this was really the original intension.

anyway: using .copy() solves both issues. the sorting issue does only occur if one object is referenced multiple times.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: It is supposed to work this way, because there may well be good reasons to have references instead of copies (there are models that need a more complex hierarchy than a simple tree structure). Anyway, I'm glad it helped - please accept my answer, then :)

Comment: i get your point. but if this is supposed to work this way then appendChild should also work correct with multiple instances and not append them between existing nodes :-)

Answer (score -1):

I guess , as you are using mxml to declare the xml data, it is considered as Bindable no matter what.
You should use the XML object in Actionscript and then try doing this.
That might be the issue here, as in ActionScript, you need to explicitly use the [Bindable] tag to have this binding behaviour.And using mxml, would automatically initilalize it as bindable.

Can you try that and let us know?

EIDT 1: It seems that the behaviour is consistent and the answer I have posted is not right.I am simultaneously searching for a solution.

Comment: Using AS3 XML object leads to the same behaviour. if one xml gets append a second time it will not append at the end but on index(1). Also changing the original object will auto-change the mainconfig object.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with binding at all. You should delete this answer.

Comment: @weltraumpirat Or I can suggest alternative ways and edit the answer instead.Thanks for the suggestion.